# Firefox Master Password (ssh-agent)

Tags: firefox, passwords

I use the master password feature of Firefox, and I also use SSH keys to login to a bunch of UNIX machines.  For SSH, there is a very useful application called ssh-agent that runs in the background knowing the required information about unlocking the key so you don't have to type the question every single time you want to connect.

I open and close Firefox a lot, so I was curious, is there a way to have Firefox run in the background (preferrably doing nothing, but the whole process would be fine I guess as well) so that I don't have to type my master password every single time I open Firefox?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the ideal solution, but you could use [**MinimizeToTray Revived**](http://tn123.ath.cx/mintrayr/) and set it up so it minimizes Firefox to the tray instead of closing it, even if you use the Close icon in the title bar.

[image]

Comment: I just tried that extension and I realized after I had installed it that there is no such thing as "minimize" in my window manager because it's a tiling window manager...

Thanks, though!